# JSON Schema for (Major Minor Patch) Versioning

Tags: jsonschema

How do I enforce Major Minor Patch versioning in a JSON Schema?

For example, this would validate:

`{ "version": "1.0.1" }`

This would NOT validate:

`{ "version": "1.0" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, example:

```
"version": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)$",
    "description": "Version (Major, Minor, Patch) identifier"
},
```